# heroku nodejs deploy errors, require modules

Tags: node.js, heroku, deployment

I have followed the instructions but it stil doesnt work. My repository is this:
https://github.com/diegoarcega/learning_react

Procfile

```
web: node index.js
```

index.js

```
var cool = require('cool-ascii-faces');
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');

var app = express();

var DIST_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname + '/../dist');

app.set('port', (process.env.PORT || 5000));

app.use('/assets/', express.static(DIST_DIR + '/assets'));

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.send('hello');
});
app.get('/cool', function(request, response) {
  response.send(cool());
});


app.listen(app.get('port'), function() {
  console.log('Listening port ' + app.get('port'))
});
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "learning_react",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "practising react",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "kill": "fuser -k 30000/tcp",
    "start": "node index.js",
    "serve": "node index.js",
    "dev": "NODE_ENV=development babel-node server/server.js",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "clean": "rimraf dist/ ",
    "copy": "copyfiles -f src/index.html src/favicon.ico dist",
    "prod": "npm run clean && webpack --config webpack.config.dist.js -p && npm run copy",
    "dist": "NODE_ENV=production babel-node server/server.js ",
    "deploy": "surge --project ./dist --domain diegoarcega-react.surge.sh"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "https://github.com/diegoarcega/learning_react"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "REACT"
  ],
  "engines": {
    "node": "4.4.5",
    "npm": "3.9.6"
  },
  "author": "Diego Arcega",
  "license": "BSD-2-Clause",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/diegoarcega/learning_react/issues"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.12.0",
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.9.1",
    "cool-ascii-faces": "^1.3.4",
    "firebase": "^3.0.5",
    "material-ui": "^0.15.1",
    "muicss": "^0.6.5",
    "q": "^1.4.1",
    "react": "~15.1.0",
    "react-dom": "~15.1.0",
    "react-redux": "~4.4.5",
    "react-router": "~2.4.1",
    "react-tap-event-plugin": "^1.0.0",
    "redux": "~3.5.2",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.1.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-cli": "^6.10.1",
    "babel-core": "~6.9.1",
    "babel-loader": "~6.2.4",
    "babel-plugin-transform-es2015-function-name": "^6.9.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-es2015-literals": "^6.8.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-es2015-template-literals": "^6.8.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-runtime": "^6.9.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "~6.9.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "~6.5.0",
    "babel-preset-react-hmre": "^1.1.1",
    "babel-preset-react-optimize": "^1.0.1",
    "copyfiles": "^1.0.0",
    "css-loader": "^0.23.1",
    "express": "~4.13.4",
    "file-loader": "^0.8.5",
    "object-assign": "^4.1.0",
    "react-css-modules": "^3.7.6",
    "react-tap-event-plugin": "^1.0.0",
    "react-thunk": "^1.0.0",
    "style-loader": "^0.13.1",
    "url-loader": "^0.5.7",
    "webpack": "~1.13.1",
    "webpack-dev-middleware": "^1.6.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^1.14.1",
    "webpack-hot-middleware": "^2.10.0"
  }
}
```

I am just trying to make it work first. The error log is this:

```
2016-07-06T17:00:56.197239+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2016-07-06T17:01:00.211013+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `node index.js`
2016-07-06T17:01:01.580923+00:00 app[web.1]: module.js:327
2016-07-06T17:00:54.456548+00:00 heroku[api]: Deploy 23f2e63 by diegoarcega@gmail.com
2016-07-06T17:01:01.580940+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.<anonymous> (/app/index.js:2:15)
2016-07-06T17:01:01.580940+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
2016-07-06T17:01:02.228107+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2016-07-06T17:01:02.212126+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2016-07-06T17:01:01.580941+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
2016-07-06T17:01:01.580942+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:441:10)
2016-07-06T17:01:01.580939+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module._load (module.js:276:25)
2016-07-06T17:01:01.580939+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
2016-07-06T17:01:01.580940+00:00 app[web.1]:     at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
2016-07-06T17:01:01.580940+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.<anonymous> (/app/index.js:2:15)
2016-07-06T17:01:01.580940+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
2016-07-06T17:01:01.580941+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
2016-07-06T17:01:02.228107+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2016-07-06T17:01:02.212126+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2016-07-06T17:02:12.435185+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation started
2016-07-06T17:02:12.435194+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation finished
2016-07-06T17:02:12.782559+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2016-07-06T17:02:17.345331+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `node index.js`
2016-07-06T17:02:19.470185+00:00 app[web.1]: module.js:327
2016-07-06T17:02:19.470199+00:00 app[web.1]:     throw err;
2016-07-06T17:02:19.470211+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: Cannot find module 'express'
2016-07-06T17:02:19.470212+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:325:15)
2016-07-06T17:02:19.470217+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
2016-07-06T17:02:19.470217+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:441:10)
2016-07-06T17:02:20.579075+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2016-07-06T17:02:20.600663+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2016-07-06T17:02:12.174712+00:00 heroku[api]: Deploy 23f2e63 by diegoarcega@gmail.com
```

Answer (score 0):

figured it out, never forget to install express in dependencies instead of devDependencies ;)